# md5 search using exceptions

Tags: python, exception, md5, httplib

```
import httplib
import re 

md5 = raw_input('Enter MD5: ') 

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.md5.rednoize.com")
conn.request("GET", "?q="+ md5) 
try:
     response = conn.getresponse()
     data = response.read() 
     result = re.findall('<div id="result" >(.+?)</div', data)
     print result
except:
     print "couldnt find the hash"

raw_input()
```

I know I'm probably implementing the code wrong, but which exception should I use for this? if it cant find the hash then raise an exception and print "couldnt find the hash"

Comment: I would like to encourage the use of named exceptions, like `except IOError` for handling exceptions (python 3 will flag the non named exceptions as errors too).  This would help you understand this particular problem a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since re.findall doesn't raise exceptions, that's probably not how you want to check for results.  Instead, you could write something like

```
result = re.findall('<div id="result" >(.+?)</div', data)
if result:
    print result
else:
    print 'Could not find the hash'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you realy like to have an exception there you have to define it:

```
class MyError(Exception):
   def init(self, value):
       self.value = value
   def str(self):
       return repr(self.value)
```

try:
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read() 
    result = re.findall('(.+?)</div', data)
    if not result:
        raise MyError("Could not find the hash")
except MyError:
   raise